# PyQGIS script processing: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'

Tags: pyqgis, unicode

I'm beginner.
I try to use a code that works to create a script processing.
The code creates folder and subfolder using the value os a column.
This is then processing script

```
import os
##Crea folder and subfolder=name
##Vector=group
##layer=vector
##idx=field layer
##path=folder

#layer = iface.activeLayer()
#idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('NAME')  
#path = "D:\\GIS\\_Temp\\"


for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    if not os.path.exists(path + attrs[idx]):
        os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx])


for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    foto=os.path.join(attrs[idx], attrs[idx]+"_foto")
#    foto= attrs[idx]+'\\'+attrs[idx]+'_foto'
    if not os.path.exists(path + foto):
        os.makedirs(path + foto)
    else:
        continue    

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    doc= os.path.join(attrs[idx], attrs[idx]+"_documenti")
    if not os.path.exists(path + doc):
        os.makedirs(path + doc)
    else:
        continue       

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    vid= os.path.join(attrs[idx], attrs[idx]+"_video")
    if not os.path.exists(path + vid):
        os.makedirs(path + vid)
    else:
        continue
```

but It returns this error: `'unicode' object has no attribute 'getFeatures'`  .
and I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Try changing `##layer=vector` to `##Layer=vector`. Then before your first `for` loop, try adding `layer = processing.getObject(Layer)`

Comment: Changing `##layer=vector to ##Layer=vector` the layer form doesn't appear. Using another name for the variable and adding `layer = processing.getObject(Layer)` It doesn't work and the error is `list indices must be integers, not unicode`

Comment: That error is due to the `fieldNameIndex` requiring the index of the field instead of the name :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made some tweaks but I tested the first part of your code which worked:

```
##Create folder and subfolder=name
##Layer=vector
##Field=field Layer
##Path=folder

import os
layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Field)
path = Path + "/"

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    if not os.path.exists(path + attrs[idx]):
        os.makedirs(path + attrs[idx])
```

You can try adding the rest of your code to the script and see if it works.

Comment: This time:
`coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, QPyNullVariant`

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Did the error occur using the code I posted or when you added the rest of your code?

Comment: I'm trying with a different shapefile and I think it works.

Comment: @DanielePiccolo - Most welcome, glad it worked :)